# How can I tell a code not to do anything if a rollover list is empty?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to show and hide some info using a rollover list in the box "B2" but if the list has no value selected, how can I tell my code not to do anything ?

When the rolloverlist has no value selected like that  :

[image]

The logger say this :

[image]

Here is my code :

```
function SOLO_SHOW_001() {


  var COPYsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PLANNING_DATA_COPY");
  var PROsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("0_LISTE PROJETS");


  //commencer par réinitialiser les lignes dans le COPYsheet

  COPYsheet.getRange("A2:BO2500").setFormulaR1C1(COPYsheet.getRange("A1").getFormulaR1C1());


  //masquer les projets qui n'ont pas "B2" comme Project Manager

  var name = PROsheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
  Logger.log(name)

  var d2cleanervalues = COPYsheet.getRange(2, 4, COPYsheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();
  for (let i = 0; i < d2cleanervalues.length; i++) {
    if (d2cleanervalues[i][0] != (name)) {
      COPYsheet.getRange(2 + i, 1, 1, 1).setValue("");
      COPYsheet.getRange(2 + i, 2, 1, 1).setValue("");
      COPYsheet.getRange(2 + i, 3, 1, 1).setValue("");
      COPYsheet.getRange(2 + i, 4, 1, 1).setValue("");
      COPYsheet.getRange(2 + i, 5, 1, 1).setValue("");
      COPYsheet.getRange(2 + i, 6, 1, 1).setValue("");
      COPYsheet.getRange(2 + i, 7, 1, 1).setValue("");
      COPYsheet.getRange(2 + i, 8, 1, 1).setValue("");
      COPYsheet.getRange(2 + i, 9, 1, 1).setValue("");

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: After `var name =` simply add `if( name === "" ) return;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm writing this answer as a community wiki, since the issue was resolved from the comments section, in order to provide a proper response to the question.

One way to check if range `B2` is empty, after the line:

```
var name = PROsheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
```

you can use:

```
if( name === "" ) return;
```

As an alternative, you can also use the `isBlank()` method, the code would look like this:

```
function SOLO_SHOW_001() {
  var COPYsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PLANNING_DATA_COPY");
  var PROsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("0_LISTE PROJETS");

  //commencer par réinitialiser les lignes dans le COPYsheet
  COPYsheet.getRange("A2:BO2500").setFormulaR1C1(COPYsheet.getRange("A1").getFormulaR1C1());

  //masquer les projets qui n'ont pas "B2" comme Project Manager
  var name = PROsheet.getRange("B2");

  if (name.isBlank())
    return;

  Logger.log(name.getValue())

  var d2cleanervalues = COPYsheet.getRange(2, 4, COPYsheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();
  for (let i = 0; i < d2cleanervalues.length; i++) {
    if (d2cleanervalues[i][0] != (name.getValue())) {
      COPYsheet.getRange(2 + i, 1, 1, 1).setValue("");
      COPYsheet.getRange(2 + i, 2, 1, 1).setValue("");
      COPYsheet.getRange(2 + i, 3, 1, 1).setValue("");
      COPYsheet.getRange(2 + i, 4, 1, 1).setValue("");
      COPYsheet.getRange(2 + i, 5, 1, 1).setValue("");
      COPYsheet.getRange(2 + i, 6, 1, 1).setValue("");
      COPYsheet.getRange(2 + i, 7, 1, 1).setValue("");
      COPYsheet.getRange(2 + i, 8, 1, 1).setValue("");
      COPYsheet.getRange(2 + i, 9, 1, 1).setValue("");
    }
  }
}
```

## References:

- [isBlank()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isblank)